# Overlaying lines and aggregating their values for overlapping segments using R?

Tags: r, merge

I have a number of routes (5 in this 
[example data](https://github.com/npct/pct-data/blob/master/test-data/airport.geojson))
stored in a
`SpatialLinesDataFrame` called `r`. These have different origins but all
converge on the same destination
([Manchester Airport](http://www.manchesterairport.co.uk/)):

[image: lines]

Each contains the variable `All`, representing
[data](https://github.com/npct/pct) 
on the number of people regularly using each route.

How can I merge the lines such that the sections where they overlap are allocated a value of 
`sum(All)` for all the lines passing through there?

The red and yellow lines, for example, have `All` values of 210 and 395,
so the orange line going north-south should be a segment with a value of
605:

[image: overlap]

```
> r_overlap$All + r[4,]$All
[1] 605
```

But I need all the merged lines in one layer, with each new Lines object representing a segment with a single `sum(All)` value, not just 1 as above.

The data above is stored at [raw.githubusercontent.com/npct/pct-data/master/test-data/airport.geojson](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/npct/pct-data/master/test-data/airport.geojson)  so the solution can be demonstrable and reproducible.
An R-based solution would be preferable to me.

The below code was used to load and view the data using the new [geojsonio](https://github.com/ropensci/geojsonio) and [leaflet](https://github.com/rstudio/leaflet) packages:

```
pkgs <- c("geojsonio", "leaflet", "sp")
lapply(pkgs, library, character.only = T)
download.file("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/npct/pct-data/master/test-data/airport.geojson", destfile = "l.geojson", method = "wget")
r <- geojsonio::geojson_read("l.geojson")

plot(r) # check the data is there
r@data # look at the data

r_overlap <- gIntersection(r[1,], r[4,])
plot(r)
plot(r_overlap, col = "red", add = T, lwd = 5)

r_overlap$All + r[4,]$All

leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addPolylines(data = r, color = c("red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "orange"))
```

Comment: geojsonio is non-CRAN, yes? This: devtools::install_github("ropensci/geojsonio")

Comment: Yes that's right. Equally `r <- readOGR("l.geojson", layer = "OGRGeoJSON")` works - just playing with new packages - no idea if they're any different in terms of performance - `geojson_read` is shorter is only difference I see.

Comment: So your output is a set of simple linear features corresponding to the sections of road in that network with an attribute that is the total for all the input simple linear features that go over it? I think rgeos::gOverlaps and gIntersection will be the key here...

Comment: Yes I think that's a fair summary of the problem. Any example code? `plot(gIntersection(r[1, ], r[2, ]))` shows it's pulling out the joint geometry - major step forward. But still cannot see how to generalise the solution. My approach would be to build a double or triple nested `for` loop that starts at `gIntersection(r[1, ], r[2, ])` and ends and `gIntersection(r[4, ], r[5, ])` at sums at each stage until there are no more overlaps. Sound like a reasonable approach? If so I'll try it. @Spacedman

Comment: Seems to me this approach is going to require something that gives the opposite of gIntersection, like a gDifference. It's easy enough to get all the overlapping segments with the summed attribute, but then need to merge in all the pieces that didn't overlap (i.e. the result of my hypothetical gDifference function).

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Any example code would also be very useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here you go. A couple of utility functions and then the meat in one function (and no `for` loops :))

```
islines <- function(g1, g2){
    ## return TRUE if geometries intersect as lines, not points
    inherits(gIntersection(g1,g2),"SpatialLines")
}

sections <- function(sl){
    ## union and merge and disaggregate to make a
    ## set of non-overlapping line segments
    disaggregate(gLineMerge(gUnion(sl,sl)))
}

aggit <- function(sldf, attr, fun=sum){
    ## simplify down to SpatialLines
    sl = as(sldf, "SpatialLines")
    ## get the line sections that make the network
    slu = sections(sl)
    ## overlay network with routes
    overs = over(slu, sl, returnList=TRUE)
    ## overlay is true if end points overlay, so filter them out:
    overs = lapply(1:length(overs), function(islu){
        Filter(function(isl){
            islines(sl[isl,],slu[islu,])
        }, overs[[islu]])
    })
    ## now aggregate the required attribute using fun():
    aggs = sapply(overs, function(os){fun(sldf[[attr]][os])})

    ## make a SLDF with the named attribute:
    sldf = SpatialLinesDataFrame(slu, data.frame(Z=aggs))
    names(sldf)=attr
    sldf
}

lineLabels <- function(sldf, attr){
    text(coordinates(gCentroid(sldf,byid=TRUE)),labels=sldf[[attr]])
}
```

Usage:

```
> r <- readOGR("airport.geojson", layer = "OGRGeoJSON")
> ag = aggit(r,"All")
> plot(ag)
> lineLabels(ag,"All")
```

`ag` is now a spatial lines data frame with the aggregated variable. The plot lets you check it all adds up. Because your routes are a bit like a river network, you can see how the "flows" add up at the junctions:

[image]

Seems right to me...